# Valid Alternative Proof to an Elementary Number Theory question in congruences?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

So, I've recently started teaching myself elementary number theory (since it does not require any specific mathematical background and it seems like a good way to keep my brain in shape until my freshman college year) using Elementary Number Theory by Underwood Dudley. I've run across the following question:

> Show that every prime (except $2$ or $3$) is congruent to $1$ or $3$ (mod $4$)

Now I am aware of one method of proof, which is looking at all the residues of $p$ (mod $4$) and eliminating the improbable ones. But before that, I found another possible way of proving it.

Since $p$ must be odd: $p$  $\equiv$ $1$ (mod $2$)

We can write this as: 2$|$$(p-1)$

But since $p$ is odd we can also say: 2$|$$(p-3)$

If $a|b$ and $c|d$ then $ac|bd$, then it follows that:

$4|(p-1)(p-3)$

The $3$ possibilites then are:

$1.$ $4|(p-1)(p-3)$

$2.$ $4|(p-1)$

$3.$ $4|(p-3)$

Thus, by the definition of congruence, we have the 3 possibilites:

$1.$ $p \equiv 1$ (mod $4$)

$2.$ $p \equiv 3$ (mod $4$)

$3.$ $4|(p-1)(p-3) = 4|p^2-4p+3$ therefore $p^2-4p+3 = 4m$

Then $p^2+3 = 4m +4p$.

Set $m+p=z$

Then from $p^2+3 = 4z$ it follows that $p^2 \equiv -3$ (mod $4$) (Is this correct?)

Can anyone please tell me if this is a valid proof? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Taken the first possibility into account. I also realize that there are much simpler proofs but I was curious as to whether this approach also works.

Comment: It’s clear that $4\mid p-1$ gives you $p\equiv1\pmod 4$ and that $4\mid p-3$ gives you $p\equiv3\pmod 4$, but how are you dealing with the first case, $4\mid(p-1)(p-3)$?

Comment: The result is so easy that possibly you had the right argument in your head. But you listed 3 possibilities and only seemed to deal with the second and third. So the argument is certainly not persuasive. In addition it is more complicated than the problem deserves.

Comment: Let me note that (I am not sure whether you are asserting this or not) that if $4|xy$ is true, it is not necessarily the case that "at least one of $4|x$ and $4|y$ should be true." For example, $4|14\times 18$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your proof, but put it more simply, the congruence
$$
p \equiv 1 \pmod{2}
$$ 
is equivalent to
$$
\text{either}\quad
p \equiv 1 \pmod{4},
\quad\text{or}\quad
p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}.
$$
This is simply because if $p \equiv 0, 2 \pmod{4}$, then $p \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$.

An then, note that the prime $3$ does fit in, $3 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

In case 1, you still have the possibility that $2|(p-1)$ (but not $4|(p-1)$), and that $2|(p-3)$ (but not $4|(p-3)$).

Here is an update to your approach that will work.  We know that $p-1$ is even.  If it's a multiple of 4 then $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.  Otherwise, $\frac{p-1}{2}=2m+1$, an odd number ($m$ is some integer).  Then we multiply to get $p-1=4m+2$ and $p-3=4m$.  Hence $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$.